# cannot print listRasters

Tags: python, raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'm trying to run this very simple script to check a problem in another more comlpex one.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace= 'C:\\Users\\Umberto\\Desktop\\Prove_Script\\Karakoram\\temporary_01'

rst= arcpy.listRasters ()
print rst
```

I didn't find out what's the matter so far. In python console within arcgis it works without any problem. It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-  packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File     "C:\Users\Umberto\Documents\UniversitᝐhD\Karakoram\MODIS_Pakistan\Script\test_listClip.py",     line 4, in <module>
    rst= arcpy.listRasters ()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'listRasters'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arcpy.ListRasters is capitalised, your code should be:

```
rst= arcpy.ListRasters ()
```

Comment: so simple... Thank You so much, the other time I've been using this function I didn't do such a mistake...